# UISwipeGesture on imageView within tableView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitableview

I'm trying to add a swipe `gesture(left/right)` on an `UIImageView` within my `tableViewCell`. I have everything working, however, i'm having trouble when I `swipe(left/right)` the image show change.

Here's my code to add my swipe gesture to my within `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
resultsImageFileOne[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
(imageOneData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
      let imageOne = UIImage(data: imageOneData!)
      //cell.imageView.image = imageOne <- will set image to UIImageView

      self.pictureOne = imageOne //global
  }
}

resultsImageFileTwo[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
(imageTwoData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
      let imageTwo = UIImage(data: imageTwoData!)
      //cell.imageView.image = imageTwo <- will set image to UIImageView

      self.pictureTwo = imageTwo //global
  }
}

 var swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeImage:")
 swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

 var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeImage:")
 swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right

 cell.mainDrawView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
 cell.mainDrawView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

My `Selector method`: it prints out the correct direction except that I can't change the image that is inside the cell from this outside method. When a swipe happens it crashes saying it found nil.

```
func swipeImage(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

var newCell: tableViewCell = tableViewCell()

if (sender.direction == .Left){
    println("Swiped Left")

//change image in TableViewCell
newCell.imageView.image = pictureOne
}
if (sender.direction == .Right){        
   println("Swiped Right")
   //change image in TableViewCell
   newCell.imageView.image = pictureOne
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question as your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442848/switching-images-by-uiswipegesture-in-tableviewcell ?

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure if i should delete it. I did the scrollview, which it worked but for this app, swipe on the image is what i'm looking for. The question is phrased different with extra/different lines of code. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow. should i delete it or keep?

Comment: I'm not sure either. A swipe on the image-in-scroll-view changes it in response to the swipe, so why was that a bad solution?

Comment: I have another UIImageView under it. When the swipe happens on the top UIImageView, should change instantly because when the user see it, they will see both (UIImageView + UIIImageView) as one single image. The scroll will show the missing parts of the bottom image.

Comment: If the goal is to change images instantly, then I do not see the purpose of having two UIImageViews.